# leaflet realtime latlng out of circle boundaries alert

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I am using leaflet for real time user tracking on maps. I drawn the circle as boundaries for all users. If the user out of the boundary I need to alert the message. I am tracking user well. Only I need to alert the message of the user out of boundary.

```
var shipLayer = L.layerGroup();
var ships = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'images/marker.png',
  iconSize: [16, 20]
});
var popup;
var region;
var fen = {
  lat: "17.4468",
  lng: "78.3922"
};
var i = 1;
var realtime = L.realtime(

  function(success, error) {
    var ship = mockShip();
    success(ship);
  }, {
    interval: refresh * 1000,
    getFeatureId: function(featureData) {
      return featureData.properties.userName;
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      region = '';
      if (typeof ship === "undefined" || ship === null) {
        var title = feature.properties.userName + " - " + feature.properties.gpsTime;
        popup = L.popup()
          .setLatLng(latlng)
          .setContent(feature.properties.userName + '<br/>' + feature.properties.gpsTime + '<br/>BatteryInfo:' + feature.properties.batteryInfo + '%')
          .openOn(map);
        marker = L.marker(latlng, {
          title: title,
          icon: ships
        });
        // this is my code for alert
        if (fen.lat < feature.properties.latitude && fen.lng < feature.properties.longitude) {
          alert('hi');
        }
        //end
        region = L.circle(fen, 450, {
          color: 'red',
          fillColor: '#f03',
          fillOpacity: 0
        }).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup(popup);
        marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
          this.openPopup();
        });
        marker.on('mouseout', function(e) {
          this.closePopup();
        });
        marker.addTo(shipLayer);
        return marker;
      }
    }
  }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `distanceTo` method of `L.LatLng` to calculate the distance between two coordinates:

> Returns the distance (in meters) to the given LatLng calculated using the Haversine formula.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

```
// Get L.LatLng object of the circle
var circleLatLng = circle.getLatLng();

// Get L.LatLng object of the marker
var markerLatLng = marker.getLatLng();

// Calculate distance:
var distance = circleLatLng.distanceTo(markerLatLng);

// Use distance in a condition:
if (distance > 450) {
    // Out of bounds, do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with turf.js:

```
marker = L.marker(latlng, {
  title: title,
  icon: ships
});
region = L.circle(fen, 450, {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0
}).addTo(map);
if (turf.distance(marker.toGeoJSON(), region.toGeoJSON()) * 1000 > 450) {
  alert('You are outside the circle!');
}
```

[`turf.distance`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_distance.html) will return the distance between two GeoJSON points. The result is multiplied by 1000 here because `L.circle` uses meters for the radius, while `turf.distance` defaults to kilometers. Here is a simple fiddle showing this at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/nv2tL6mz/

When you click outside the circle, the alert will be triggered.

Comment: FYI: No need to pull in an extra lib like Turf for this since `L.LatLng` objects have a `distanceTo` method. Hence my answer ;)